# No Wix , exportando dados para a url em javascript e fornecendo dados

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento

Olá, tudo bem ? Estou precisando de ajuda com uma questão. Estou tentando enviar dados e redirecionar a um domínio diferente através de um botão na criação de site no [www.wix.com](http://www.wix.com), os dados são status, nome completo, email e id. A linguagem que se utiliza é javascript.

Porém , se coloco desta forma,
Fica com esta mensagem sem erro mas de carregando :Loading the code for the "Page" page. To debug this code, open x6jlx.js in your browser's Developer Tools.

A pergunta é se está realmente correto, pois está somente para membros privados pagantes , pois fica neste loop e apresenta mais nada. Se clico no botão também não faz nada na área de vizualizar.

```
    import { currentMember } from 'wix-members';
    import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
    export function button2_click(event) {wixLocation.to("www.page.com" + currentMember.getMember()
  .then((member) => {
    const id = member._id;
    const status = member.status

    const fullName = `${member.contactDetails.firstName} ${member.contactDetails.lastName}`;
    return member;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }));
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: [`currentMember.getMember()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-members-backend/currentmember/getmember?utm_campaign=ma_cyberchimps.com_wixcode&experiment_id=cyberchimps.com%5Earticle1) retorna um objeto [`Promisse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) e portanto trata-se uma operação assíncrona, invoque [`wixLocation.to()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/to) dentro do método [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muita pesquisa no fórum da Velo da Wix, descobri a API do `members-wix`, no momento encontra-se com problemas, o que resulta buscar funções na users-wix, porém está depreciada, o que esconde funções no site da velo dificultando o acesso a informação. Porém, após copiar uma função de migração da `users-wix` para `members-wix`, juntamente com a autenticação de `members-wix`, funcionou perfeitamente , quero agradecer também a ajuda de Mosh Feu https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu, que contribuiu para que entendesse e melhorasse esse código, pois fiz a pergunta em inglês também.

```
import { currentMember } from 'wix-members';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import { authentication } from 'wix-members';
// NOTE: This example uses the new wix-members.currentMember.getMember()
//       function, which replaces wix-users.currentUser.
//       See the function description for more information, and
//       line 36 for the deprecated example.

// ...

currentMember.getMember('FULL')
    .then((member) => {
        // Replaces currentUser.id
        const id = member._id;

        // Replaces currentUser.loggedIn
        const loggedIn = member ? true : false;

        // Replaces currentUser.getEmail()
        const loginEmail = member.loginEmail;
        const contactEmails = member.contactDetails.emails;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

currentMember.getRoles()
    .then((roles) => {
        // Replaces currentUser.role and currentUser.getRoles()
        return roles;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

// NOTE: This example uses the deprecated
//       wix-users.currentUser object.

import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

// ...

let user = wixUsers.currentUser;

let userId = user.id; // "r5cme-6fem-485j-djre-4844c49"
let isLoggedIn = user.loggedIn; // true

user.getEmail()
    .then((email) => {
        let userEmail = email; // "user@something.com"
    });

user.getRoles()
    .then((roles) => {
        let firstRole = roles[0];
        let roleName = firstRole.name; // "Role Name"
        let roleDescription = firstRole.description; // "Role Description"
    });

user.getPricingPlans()
    .then((pricingPlans) => {
        let firstPlan = pricingPlans[0];
        let planName = firstPlan.name; // "Gold"
        let startDate = firstPlan.startDate; // Wed Aug 29 2018 09:39:41 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
        let expiryDate = firstPlan.expiryDate; // Thu Nov 29 2018 08:39:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    });
export async function button2_click(event) {
    authentication.onLogin(async (member) => {
        const loggedInMember = await member.getMember();
        const memberId = loggedInMember._id;
        console.log(`Member ${memberId} logged in:`, loggedInMember);
    });

    const member = await currentMember.getMember();
    const id = member._id;
    const status = member.status;
    const email = member.loginEmail
    const fullName = `${member.contactDetails.firstName} ${member.contactDetails.lastName}`;
    const userDetails = JSON.stringify({ id, status, fullName ,email });

    wixLocation.to(`https://www.url.com/?user=${encodeURIComponent(userDetails)}`);
}
```